# Get total count of matching string from different sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count

I have the multiple sheets in a single workbook.

The first sheet is having summary details:

[image]

Other sheets are like details as show below:

[image]

I want to get total count `name` occurred in all the sheets in workbook.

Expected output should be:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on your sheetnames, try something like:

```
=SUM(--(TOCOL(Sheet2:Sheet3!A:A,1)=B2))
```

Comment: Ah, yes! Forgot that `TOCOL` can take a 3D reference. Very useful - makes the old volatile set-up redundant.

Comment: I didn't know TOCOL is compatible with 3D reference. Actually, that function is not even listed on official sources: [Create a reference to the same cell range on multiple worksheets](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-c906f8b4-c648-4aa0-8063-65d38d03370f#:~:text=Click%20the%20tab%20for%20the,formula%2C%20and%20then%20press%20Enter.) Thumbs up

Answer (score 3):

Create a list of all relevant worksheet names and store it within Name Manager, as *SheetList*, say.

Your formula is then:

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT("'"&SheetList&"'!A:A"),B2))`

where I've assumed that the column to be queried in each of those worksheets is `column A` and that the first entry in the *Summary* sheet for which you wish to obtain a count is in cell `B2`.

Copy down to give results for further entries in `B3`, `B4`, etc.

Comment: This work even on Excel 2007. I'm not friendly with INDIRECT but for older versions is the only way. Thumbs up!